# ANT creating a WAR file and excluding a word

Tags: java, ant, war

When building my WAR file I want to exclude all files that have the word "test" in them. Is there a way to exclude all those files in one exclude tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, using something like this in a `<fileset>`:

```
<exclude name="**/*test*"/>
```

In fact, this is the [first example in the Ant manual](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/fileset.html) for `<FileSet>`.

Answer (score 0):

yes

```
<war ... excludes="**/**test**" />
```

or by using a fileset

Comment: I don't think `**test**` makes any sense, does it?